# Databinding to repeate dynamic object creation

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, data-binding, dynamic

I can't find an exact word to describe my problem (so sorry for that).

What I want to do is :

Create a **Stackpanel** which will hold *vertically* other **StackPanels**, those **StackPanels** will be created dynamically depending on the number of rows in the Database, each **StackPanel** will hold two **Labels** (Title & Description) and must Databind their values from the Linq request.

[image: Dynamic Databinding]

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label x:Name="Title" />
        <Label x:Name="Description" />
    </StackPanel>
</Stackpanel>
```

I have already created my Linq request using the **ObservableCollection** & **IEnumerable**. Actually I can get the values and print them using Debug.WriteLine() command.

Can any one help me with some tips ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx)

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourObservableCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Value1}"></Label>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Value2}"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The outer StackPanel is not necessary here. The default template of ItemsControl specifies a StackPanel for the [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) property. Hence visually a (default-styled) ItemControls is a StackPanel.

Comment: I know and I agree with you @Clemens. According to the question I add to the example the outer stackpanel. It is not necessary if it wrap only the ItemsControl. ;)